# Toolbar won't display in Activity

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar

I've set my application theme to be `NoActionBar` in AndroidManifest.xml because I only want a toolbar in my activity and a few fragments, so I'm willing to set it manually for those.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I made a view for my toolbar `tb.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
    android:text="Main"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ivBell"
    android:background="@drawable/bell"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

and here's how I set it in the activity:

```
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main_toolbar, null);
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

But it doesn't show up when I launch my app - any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: Your inflated `Toolbar` has not been added to the on-screen hierarchy. You've just inflated it. You would need to add it to a `ViewGroup` in your `Activity`'s or `Fragment`'s layout.

Comment: I added it to the activity's layout and is now working - how do I get rid of or replace the toolbar in a fragment? getActivity().getSupportActionBar.hide() doesn't work :(

Answer (score 2):

Try below code:

In your `style.xml`

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:splitMotionEvents">false</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

In your `AndroidMenifest.xml`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

In your `Activity.java` or `BaseActivity.java` file add following method and call it in `onCreate` or you can directly put method's code in Activity.java's `onCreate`:

```
public void setUpToolbar(String strTitle) {
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
            title = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            title.setText(strTitle);
        }
    }
```

**Note: Don't forget to include `tb.xml` file in your activity's .xml file**

In your `Fragment.java` or `BaseFragment.java` file add following method and call it in `onCreateView` or you can directly put method's code in Fragment.java's `onCreateView`:

```
public void setupToolBarWithBackArrow(Toolbar toolbar, @Nullable String Title) {
        ActionBar actionBar;
        // If you are using BaseActivity.java then keep below code as it is otherwise replace BaseActivity with Your Activity's name
        ((BaseActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        actionBar = ((BaseActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();

        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_back); // Set null if you don't want to show back arrow
        }
        // Remove this click listener if you set null in setHomeAsUpIndicator(...)
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mActivity.onBackPressed();
            }
        });
        title = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setText(Title != null ? Title : "");
    }
```

**Note: Don't forget to include `tb.xml` file in your fragment's .xml file**

Comment: Thanks! I added it to the activity's layout and is now working - how do I get rid of or replace the toolbar in a fragment? getActivity().getSupportActionBar.hide() in the fragment doesn't work

Comment: If you are using fragment then I suggest you to include toolbar in you fragment's xml file instead of activity's xml file. If you want to use Actionbar in activity then you can assign id to included layout like <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" /> and by using that id you can set visibility of the view like toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Comment: I have added how to use toolbar in Fragment. See my updated answer.